# How to make Session variable last longer than the login

Tags: .net, session

I have this in my web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="70"/>
```

and:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Index" timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

I also have this:

```
Session.Timeout = 70;
```

So, after an hour or so, the user is still logged in, but the session is null and my program crashes. Any idea?

Comment: At what interval is the application restarted on the iis if idle?

Comment: @RuneFS I'm sorry I don't understand. I don't use IIS.

Comment: What server are you using then?

Comment: @RuneFS Well I just run my program and it opens itself in a browser, with localhost.

Comment: Check if setting `slidingExpiration="true"` can solve your issue. See [FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx) for details.

Comment: Localhost is served by a server if you're using VS it Cassini or iis. It is always worth knowing the tools and the platform you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code in the question is correct. However, everytime I rebuild my code, the session was lost. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to put a check if your session is null then redirect to login page.**

Comment: That was not my question. This is not an answer.

Comment: @scree might not solve your issue but you till ought to o it since at some point the session is going to be null